# Considering the potential upcoming legislation in the U.S., what moves can someone make before it goes into effect to protect themselves?

Tags: security, government

The upcoming infrastructure bill includes some crypto provisions, and it's getting a lot of attention. There are varying opinions on just how bad these provisions are, but regardless of severity they do attempt to cut at cryptocurrency in general.

Now, as we know, Bitcoin is not actually anonymous, despite much of the misinformation that spread years ago. Especially when using an exchange where they verify your identity to buy/sell.

What are some ways to protect yourself and your money/investment when it comes to potential government interference in crypto markets?
What about things miners can do to protect themselves as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now, as we know, Bitcoin is not actually anonymous, despite much of the misinformation that spread years ago. Especially when using an exchange where they verify your identity to buy/sell.

Bitcoin not being anonymous and using KYC exchanges to buy/sell are two different things. Using KYC exchange for any cryptocurrency transactions ends your privacy and anonymity.

> What are some ways to protect yourself and your money/investment when it comes to potential government interference in crypto markets?

Follow best practices:

1. Use DEX like Bisq to trade
2. Run and use your own node with Tor/i2p
3. Do not reuse addresses
4. Use coinjoin and payjoin when necessary
5. Do not share information about your addresses, transactions, nodes etc. on social media

> What about things miners can do to protect themselves as well?

1. Use non-KYC mining pools
2. If mining is done with farms and lot of ASICs maybe consider doing it in a country that has no issues with bitcoin miners

Comment: Thanks for this and the clarification on anonymity regarding KYC exchanges. That is an important distinction to make.